# how can i assign the text box value to an variable in jscript using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

how can i call get the text box value in an jscript in classic asp.below is my code

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="abd" name="abc" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function abc()
{
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
text = contenteditable.textContent;
alert(text);
document.getElementById("abd").value=text;
return text;
}
</script>

<%
var aspvariable
aspvariable=%>
<script>document.getElementById("abd").value</script>
<%
ts = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\\applications\\1.txt",true);
ts.WriteLine("This is my first FileSystemObject application.");
ts.WriteLine(aspvariable);
ts.Close();
%>
</html>
```

i cannot able to get the aspvariable value(which is the value of the txt box with id=abd),and so the resulting value inside an text file is empty.thanks in advance..

Comment: (You're not actually setting `aspvariable` to anything; in fact, I'm pretty sure your code gives a syntax error at the `aspvariable=%>` line.) The form is at the client, but asp runs on the server. To get information from the client to the server, you need to submit it (i.e. via a form submission) or otherwise add it to the `Request` (e.g. by constructing a link with the information in the querystring).

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see what you are trying to do. First of all add a submit button to your form so that it can be sent to the server. As you don't have any properties to the form tag this form will be posted back to the same page.

Then at the start of the page you will need this:

```
<%
If Request.Form<>"" Then
    aspvariable=Request("abc")
    ts = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\\applications\\1.txt",true);
    ts.WriteLine("This is my first FileSystemObject application.");
    ts.WriteLine(aspvariable);
    ts.Close();
End If
%>
```

Thats all the server side code you'll need.

If you want the form to keep the submitted text then use:

```
<input type="text" id="abd" name="abc" value="<%=aspvariable%>">
```

Comment: i tried with it but the problem is that the return value(text) from the javascript function abc() is of too long and it contains special characters to..so aspvariable=Request("abc") is not getting the value.Nothing is getting printed inside my newly created text file except  this line "This is my first FileSystemObject application."please help me with this.

Comment: below is the link for my updated code..can you please suggest me what needs to be done withis...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138983/how-can-i-assign-javascript-variable-to-vbscript-variable