# How can i assign javascript variable to vbscript variable

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding, asp-classic

How can i assign the text1 value(*javascript* value) to *vbscript* variable so that i can write that data into a 
text file using `ts.WriteLine(av)`

I tried submitting the form and getting all the values in the next .asp page and then writing it to a text file,
but my value has many alpha-numeric and special characters....so I cant achieve in that way..any help please.

```
<% Option Explicit
Const Filename = "/project.txt"    ' file to read
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim FSO
set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Filepath
Filepath = "E:\applications\FTP\project.txt"
if FSO.FileExists(Filepath) Then
    Dim file    
    set file = FSO.GetFile(Filepath)
Dim TextStream
    Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
     %>

    <form id="ValidForm"  action="">
<input type="textbox" name="ac" id="ac" value="">
    <textarea rows="100" cols="230" contenteditable>

<%  Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream  
        Dim Line
        Line = TextStream.readline
        Line = Line & vbCRLF
 Response.write Line
Loop
%>
</textarea>
</form >
<%
Response.Write "</pre><hr>"
    Set TextStream = nothing
End If
Set FSO = nothing
%>

<button onclick=abc();>save</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function abc()
{alert("1");
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
text1 = contenteditable.textContent;
//document.getElementById("ac").value=text1;
alert(text1);
}
</script>

<%
'what i should add here to get the javascript variable(text1)

set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("E:\\applications\\FTP\\shivan123.txt",true)
ts.WriteLine("This is my first FileSystemObject application.")
ts.WriteLine( )
ts.Close()
set ts=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Comment: From the looks of it you are trying to assign a client-side variable to server-side code. To do this you need to submit the value via a HTTP request to the server *(form submission, ajax call etc.)*. Remember Classic ASP code `<% %>` is processed at the server **before** the page is rendered back to the client *(Internet Browser)*.

Comment: *"I tried submitting the form and getting all the values in the next .asp page and then writing it to a text file, but my value has many alpha-numeric and special characters....so I cant achieve in that way"* That is the only way to achieve it, you can't just bypass character encoding it has to be done right. If it isn't working post your ASP code and your form submission code and we will try to advise.

Comment: @Quentin Reading between the lines the issue is actually an encoding problem, I'm sure there's plenty of duplicates for that as well.